# convert GMT time object to local time iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, gmt

I want to convert GMT Time which obtained from web service. I am getting the object like this

```
dateTime: {
           date: 23
           day: 3
           hours: 6
           minutes: 13
           month: 8
           nanos: 0
           seconds: 0
           time: 1442988780000
           timezoneOffset: 0
           year: 115
          }
```

I don't have idea how to convert this object to local phone time.

Comment: Why is the year 115? What calendar is this based on? What is the value in the time parameter?

Comment: Year 115 is 2015 (1900 + 115).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/) and [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/). See Apple's [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i)

Answer (score 1):

`Step1-` Convert data which you are getting in `Dictionary or Array`
`Step2-` Access The dictionary by `key-value` pair.
'Step3-' Refer `NSDate` from apple doc

also try this-

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2012-07-16 07:33:01";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; 
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"date : %@",date);

NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

NSDate *destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:date] autorelease];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm"];
[dateFormatters setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatters setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatters setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];
[dateFormatters setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];  
dateStr = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];
NSLog(@"DateString : %@", dateStr);
```